# Styling react-native-material-menu

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm creating a react-native-app which consists of the material menu. My app requires a vertical menu. I have set the width for the menu. I have images inside the menu to choose the font size. Somehow the images are taking padding without me setting anything.
Please help me how can I go about this.
The images in the menu are appearing cut even though it is the correct resolution. and each image is taking padding which doesn't allow all 3 to appear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIdHw.png)

Comment: i have too this question